# Silverstripe Login params

Tags: forms, parameters, silverstripe

Im trying to style my login page. My login url is website/Security/login. Im trying to locate the 'login' piece of the url. What have i done wrong below?

```
public function DisplayPageType() {
   $param = $this->request->param('Action');
   if ($param === 'login')
    {
       return 'Login';
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: If you found either answer helpful, it is a good idea to mark one as accepted. That way it can signal to visitors that come across the same issue to know there are known solutions for the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I think that won't work since the controller during render is the `Page_Controller` and not the `Security` controller. So the `$Action` param is not equal to `login`. It could be `index`, I'm not sure.

If you just want to check if you're in the login page, you can add this to your `Page_Controller`:

```
public function getIsLoginPage()
{
    return $_REQUEST['url'] == '/Security/login';
}
```

Then in your template:

```
<body class="<%if $IsLoginPage %>login-page<% end_if %>">
```

A bit dirty but it's the quickest way I know.

Another way is to leverage SilverStripe's legacy support. You can add a css file called `tabs.css` at `mysite/css/tabs.css`. If this file exists, SilverStripe will include this in the page.

You can also create templates that SilverStripe will automatically use if they exist:

- `themes/<theme_name>/Security.ss` - If you want your login page to use an entirely different layout.
- `themes/<theme_name>/Layout/Security_login.ss` - If you want to change just the content part (the `$Layout` section)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

@gpbnz is right, the `$Action` param is not equal to `login`, it actually returns `null` as accessing `$this->request` from the `Page_Controller` when accessing the `Security/login` returns a [`NullHTTPRequest`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-NullHTTPRequest.html).

To get the action, you will want to get the current controller using [`Controller::curr()`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-Controller.html#_curr). It is then as simple as calling [`getAction`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-Controller.html#_getAction) on this controller.

To confirm that the action isn't from a random controller that happens to have an action called `login`, you can check the [instanceof](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.instanceof.php) the controller like so: `Controller::curr() instanceof Security`

This check will still allow it to work for any controller that extends [`Security`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-Security.html) though which may/may not happen depending on the project.

I would stick away from actually reading the URL for the information manually though as that can create issues with maintainability in the future.

To bring this to a nice little function:

```
public function isLoginPage()
{
    $controller = Controller::curr();
    return $controller instanceof Security && $controller->getAction() == 'login';
}
```

Otherwise @gpbnz had a good suggestion of using the template system to your advantage for overriding not only the styles but the HTML around it.